# How extend this User interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm new to typescript and I'm migrating a existing project to it. On my middleware functions, that are on a separete file, there's this function:

```
const checkCampgroundOwnership = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (req.user && req.isAuthenticated()) {
    try {
      const foundCampground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);

      // does user own the campground?
      if (foundCampground && foundCampground.author.id == req.user._id) {
        next();
      } else {
        req.flash("error", "You don't have permission to do that");
        res.redirect("back");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      req.flash("error", "Campground not found");
      return res.redirect("back");
    }
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "You need to be logged in to do that");
    return res.redirect("back");
  }
};
```

On line 11, when I check if there's any foundCampground I'm getting this error on the "req.user._id": `Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'`.

On my server.ts I have this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
  next();
});
```

What I could do?

Comment: *Does* the req.user have an _id prop? If you're migrating working code I assume it does, so you need to find where User is defined and add that prop.

Comment: This req.user is from Express Request type, how can I extend this interface and add my propos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

1. Create a .d.ts file and customize as you want! My version:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv {
    MONGO_URI: string;
    GOOGLE_API: string;
    SECRET_KEY: string;
  }
}

declare namespace Mytypes {
  export interface User extends Express.User{
    _id: string;
    username: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  }
  export interface ICustomRequest<T> extends Express.Request {
    body: T;
    params: {
      id: string;
      comment_id: string;
    };
  }
}
```